# Is SQLCipher Community edition freely available?

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I wanted to use the encrypted database in my android application. I came across SQLCipher which is very nice. I am developing free apps and was wondering if I can use the SQLCipher Community edition, which as per my understanding from SQLCipher site seems to be free!

I bit new to licensing world and if anybody can confirm that my understanding is correct then it will be very helpful!

Comment: I think you'll get better idea by reading [SQLCipher Community Edition License, also SQLCipher for Android](http://sqlcipher.net/license/). Based on my experience, yes you're good to go with Apache 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can but you should add information that you use sqlcipher http://sqlcipher.net/open-source/ :
License

> SQLCipher Community Edition can be used it in both open source and
>   closed source commercial software, but you must include our BSD-style
>   license and copyright statements prominently in the application and
>   documentation.

So you should:

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>               modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
>                   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>                   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>                   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> - Neither the name of the ZETETIC LLC nor the
>                   names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
>                   derived from this software without specific prior written permission.